# Bitcoin withdrawal issue

Tags: blockchain.info

I have withdrawn BTC from an exchange to be sent to another. However, I haven't receieved it. When I check it with the transaction hash, it shows as it took so many confirmations. Can anybody tell me where the problem is? Please check my Tx hash : 1db23c2bdc95d1b889ae0489103a0d0041bd5e046c07ebefdffd81abab343978

Comment: Have you confirmed that the deposit address you sent the money to appears in the transaction https://blockchain.info/tx/1db23c2bdc95d1b889ae0489103a0d0041bd5e046c07ebefdffd81abab343978?  It needs to be exactly correct, so could be a copy/paste error etc?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes I did confirm that. It is exist and correct. Actually I am curious about, maybe my problem is about I didn't pay enough for mining fee?

Answer (score 1):

1. Double check to make sure you didn't send your coins to the address of another coin. Sending BTC to BCH (BCC) is a very common mistake.
2. If you sent the coins to the wrong address, you'll need to contact the exchange and ask them to import that private key into your BTC wallet. Whether or not they will comply depends on the exchange.